# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python

Я хочу достать фамилии с сайта с фамилиями. В ссылке при переходе на след. страницу у них меняются только номера страниц и названия букв. Поэтому я решил просто перебрать все значения до 20 листов и все буквы, чтобы вытащить в список все фамилии следующим образом:

```
s = ['а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з', 'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ', 'ы', 'ь', 'э', 'ю', 'я']
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
surnames = [] # Массив, в который буду записывать фамилии

for a in s:                       # Перебор всех букв алфавита
    for b in range(30):
        c = str(b)                # Перебор всех возможных страниц (проверка до 30 страниц на 1 букву)
    # a - буквы
    # c - цифры от 1 до 90
        part_of_link_1 = 'https://gufo.me/dict/surnames_ru?' # Собираю ссылку
        part_of_link_2 = 'page=' 
        part_of_link_3 = c       
        part_of_link_4 = '&'     
        part_of_link_5 = 'letter='
        part_of_link_6 = a

        next_link = str(part_of_link_1) + str(part_of_link_2) + part_of_link_3 + str(part_of_link_4) + str(part_of_link_5) + part_of_link_6
        # Теперь все ссылки по одной содержатся в next_link
        d = requests.get(next_link) #Проверяем
        if d.status_code == 200: # если ссылка есть
            everything_from_html_page = d.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(everything_from_html_page, 'html.parser')
            soup.prettify()
            surnames_not_filtered = soup.find_all('li') # Теперь в списке ссылки
            count = len(surnames_not_filtered)          # считаю их количество
            i = 0
            for a in range(count):
                for b in surnames_not_filtered[i]:      # тк мне нужны фамилии в ссылке, а ссылка является одним элементом списка
                                                    # то теперь вытащим фамилию из списка. Сейчас "с" - это одна фамилия (перебираются)
                    for c in b:
                        surnames += [c]  # добавляем фамилии по одной в массив
                        i += 1
        else: # если такой страницы нет
            pass # то пропускаем
```

Все фамилии (c) выводятся хорошо, но записываться в массив не хотят и ошибка:

> next_link = str(part_of_link_1) + str(part_of_link_2) + part_of_link_3 + str(part_of_link_4) + str(part_of_link_5) + part_of_link_6
>   TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Все элементы в next_link являются строковыми и фамилии заисываются в массив, но в уже конце выдает ошибку. Как убрать ошибку или сделать, чтобы он ее не замечал в конце? Заранее благодарю

Comment: Нужно дебажить, где-то вместо строки приходит число, поэтому выводит ошибку.. Или же все `part_of_link` оберните в `str`

Comment: @E1mir а как задебажить, если я с sublime text 3 пишу (нет дебага для питона), а через онлайн дебаггеры не хочет import делать?

Comment: У тебя вроде простой python скрипт, скачай бесплатную версию PyCharm, а там офигенный дебаггер, ну или же VisualStudioCode, там тоже он вроде как неплохой, только настраивать надо будет

Comment: @E1mir  Вообще все заносится же, как просто сделать программе опускание этой ошибки?

Comment: Внизу Андрей предложил один вариант который опустит данную ошибку, примени и посмотри) Вроде как должно сработать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
next_link = f'{part_of_link_1}{part_of_link_2}{part_of_link_3}{part_of_link_4}{part_of_link_5}{part_of_link_6}'
```

Comment: Ошибка исчезла, но после выполнения всего - не хочет выполнять print(surnames) (хочу посмотреть все фамилии в списке)

Comment: Все заработало! Можно документацию на то, что вы написали и причину неправильности моего кода? Благодарю

Comment: @quicky https://python-scripts.com/f-strings